# ORACLE - ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: oracle

I change OCI8 version for PHP and since this query dosn't work :

```
SELECT 'M'||to_char(to_date(OD.DATE2,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MM') PERIODE, count(*) DATA, OD.DCCPT DCCPT
FROM BDD OD
WHERE BDD = 'phone'
AND OD.SENS = 'Ent'
AND OD.DCCPT IN('PIOLUC')
AND (OD.DATE2 BETWEEN '08/03/2015' AND '08/03/2016')
group by 'M'||to_char(to_date(OD.DATE2,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'MM'), OD.CDCCPT CDCCPT
```

I got this message :

**Message:  oci_execute(): ORA-01843: not a valid month**

It works with Toad for Oracle 11. Do you have any solution ?

Thank you :)

Comment: What is the datatype of DATE2?

Comment: If `date2` is a `date` then why do you use `to_date()` to convert a `date` to a `date` value?

Comment: You have an erroneous alias in the `GROUP BY` and you are grouping by `CDCCPT` but the column you are selecting is `DCCPT`. You might want to fix those too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `OD.DATE2` is of DATE datatype, you need to explicitly convert the dates-as-strings (eg. `'08/03/2015'`) into date format.

Something like:

```
SELECT   'M'||to_char(OD.DATE2,'MM') PERIODE,
         count(*) DATA,
         OD.DCCPT DCCPT
FROM     BDD OD
WHERE    BDD = 'phone'
AND      OD.SENS = 'Ent'
AND      OD.DCCPT IN ('PIOLUC')
AND      OD.DATE2 BETWEEN to_date('08/03/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('08/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
group by 'M'||to_char(OD.DATE2,'MM'),
          OD.DCCPT;
```

Note how I have removed the `to_date` from around `OD.DATE2` in the select and group by lists, since it is a **very** bad idea to use `to_date` against something that is already a DATE.

By doing so, you force Oracle to do an implicit conversion to a string, which it will do so by using your NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter to decide what format to output the string as, before it then tries to convert it back to a date using the format mask you specified, like so:

```
to_date(to_char(od.date2, '<nls_date_format parameter>'), 'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

If the two format masks aren't the same, you will run into errors... such as the one that prompted you to post this question!

Comment: Work like a charm, I should have seen it..  Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the line:

```
OD.DATE2 BETWEEN '08/03/2015' AND '08/03/2016'
```

Then `'08/03/2015'` and `'08/03/2016'` are string literals and are not dates.

Oracle will attempt an implicit conversion from a string literal to a date using your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask and if this does not work it will throw an error.

The simple solution is not to use string literals but use date literals instead:

```
SELECT 'M'||to_char( DATE2, 'MM' ) PERIODE,
        count(*) DATA,
        DCCPT
FROM    BDD
WHERE   BDD   = 'phone'
AND     SENS  = 'Ent'
AND     DCCPT IN ( 'PIOLUC' )
AND     DATE2 BETWEEN DATE '2015-03-08' AND DATE '2016-03-08'
GROUP BY
        'M'||to_char( DATE2, 'MM' ),
        DCCPT
```

But you could also specify the format mask:

```
OD.DATE2 BETWEEN TO_DATE( '08/03/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) AND TO_DATE( '08/03/2016', 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
```