# ORA-01843: not a valid month with valid SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am trying to fetch `current date`, `week number`, `first date in the week` and `last date in the week`. SQL statement below it's working but when I'm running in Oracle Apex I get `ORA-01843: not a valid month`

```
declare
    date_value        char;
    week_value        pls_integer;
    start_date_value  char;
    end_date_value    char;
begin 
    SELECT 
         TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')),'DD.MM.YYYY')
    ,    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'WW'))
    ,    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'IW'),'DD.MM.YYYY')
    ,    TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY'),'IW'),'SUNDAY'),'DD.MM.YYYY') 
    INTO 
        date_value
    ,   week_value
    ,   start_date_value
    ,   end_date_value
    FROM DUAL;

    htp.p('<< '||'Week'|| week_value ||' >> '|| start_date_value ||' - '|| end_date_value);
end;
```

Also tried with sysdate and also works only in SQL but in PL/SQL (Oracle Apex) page throws same exception.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If CURRENT_DATE is the current date, and a date data type, why are you running it through a TO_DATE function? with a fixed format picture on it, that's going to cause an implicit date to string conversion based on the NLS settings for the format picture, which might not match your format picture for converting it back.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORACLE - ORA-01843: not a valid month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869479/oracle-ora-01843-not-a-valid-month)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` with a `DATE` (not a String) which causes Oracle to do an implicit conversion of the `DATE` to a `VARCHAR2` using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format model just so you can convert it back to a `DATE`.

So the query:

```
TO_DATE(CURRENT_DATE,'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Is effectively:

```
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    CURRENT_DATE,
    ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  'MM/DD/YYYY'
)
```

If the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` matches `MM/DD/YYYY` then your query will work - the format does not match so it does not work.

What you should be doing is not using `TO_DATE` on a `DATE` data type - it is already a `DATE` so you don't need to.

```
declare
    date_value        char(10) := TO_CHAR( CURRENT_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY' );
    week_value        pls_integer := TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE,'WW'));
    start_date_value  char(10) := TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW'),'DD.MM.YYYY');
    end_date_value    char(10) := TO_CHAR(NEXT_DAY(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'IW'),'SUNDAY'),'DD.MM.YYYY');
begin 
    htp.p('<< '||'Week'|| week_value ||' >> '|| start_date_value ||' - '|| end_date_value);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wasn't thinking this way but it's much more simple.